# Azure Data Factory Pipeline run based on parameters

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using ADF to copy data from Cosmos DB to Azure Data Lake.  I've scheduled it to run every 24 hours.  Since ADF will copy all the data from the source into the sink, I use windowStart and windowEnd parameters to filter the data.  The filtering is done on timestamp which is inside Cosmos Document DB.

To run a pipeline, I've to manually specify the windowStart and windowEnd UTC time, which is not feasible.  Is there a way to automate this?  What I want is to set the windowStart time to the (scheduled time - 1 day)  and windowEnd time to be the schedule time.  This way I can get all the data from the previous day.

The generated query is:

```
select * from c 
where c.data.timestamp >= '@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStart, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}' 
AND c.data.timestamp < '@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowEnd, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}'
```

How can I set the windowStart and windowEnd dynamically to be equal and -1 day to the scheduled time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **[schedule trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger)**, passing the following values into your pipeline. Use [adddays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#date-functions) function on your scheduled time. 
You could use ADF UI to help you edit/new the trigger.
[image]

```
"name": "trigger1",
"properties": {
    "runtimeState": "Stopped",
    "pipelines": [
        {
            "pipelineReference": {
                "referenceName": "CopyPipeline_9ca",
                "type": "PipelineReference"
            },
            "parameters": {
                "windowStart": "@adddays(trigger().scheduledTime, -1)",
                "windowEnd": "@trigger().scheduledTime"
            }
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to implement it by modifying my source query like this

select * from c 
where c.data.timestamp >= '@{formatDateTime(addhours(pipeline().TriggerTime, -24), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}' 
AND c.data.timestamp < '@{formatDateTime(pipeline().TriggerTime, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}'

I'm still pretty early with ADF.  Does the JSON document you gave a sample of, has to be implemented when using Powershell or .net?

Comment: pipeline().TriggerTime is a system variable. If it works well, you don’t need add your own parameters as what in my answer.

Comment: @MAK: Note: you do not actually need to run it through the formatDateTime functionas addhours has a format provider, e.g:     "DateToProcess": "@adddays(trigger().scheduledTime, -5, 'yyyy-MM-dd')",